# How to fetch data from JSON file and create a new file with the selected values in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby

I need to create a JSON file with details of movies that have the same genre.
This is the input JSON file:

```
[{"rating": "9.3", "movie_id": 1, "title": "The Shawshank
Redemption",  "release_date": "14 October
1994",  "director": "Frank Darabont", "year":
"1994", "genre": ["Crime", "Drama"], "running_time": "142 min"},

{"rating": "9.2",
"movie_id": 2, "title": "The Godfather",  "director": "Francis Ford",
"year": "1972",
"genre": ["Crime", "Drama"], "running_time": "175 min"},

{"rating": "9.1", "movie_id": 3,  "title": "The Godfather:
Part II",  "release_date": "", "director": "Francis Ford Coppola", "year":
"1974", "genre": ["Crime", "Drama"], "running_time": "200 min"},

{"rating": "9.0",  "movie_id": 12,  "title": "Interstellar",
"release_date": "7 November 2014",
"director": "Christopher Nolan", "year": "2014", 
"genre": ["Adventure",      "Sci-Fi"],
 "running_time": "169 min"},]
```

How do I check the genre of all movies and create a new JSON file with all the movies with the "crime" and "drama" genre?

Comment: *"How to check if the genre of the movie is same in ruby?"* - can you be more specific and add desired output?

Comment: I want to create a new json file with all the movie of genre of "crime" and "drama" by checking the genre of all movies.

Comment: @AkashGhosh what is your problem? Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i have loaded the json file but not able to get how to match the genres.. can u help me with that?

Comment: You need to iterate over the array of movies and get a value of genre key. It's pretty simple, try it. I suggest you to read some basic about Ruby Iterations and Ruby arrays. https://teamtreehouse.com/library/iteration-with-each for example.

Comment: Thanks for that but how to convert json to array?

Comment: That's already array `[ .. ]`.

Comment: @akash read json parsing. Lots of material are available on string and json manipulation.If you are reading the json file as string then you have to json parse to make it as json object which will be array. You can then use  include? to match array like arr.select{|item| item["genre"].include?"Crime"}

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Comment: Your input JSON data is mangled; It's been wrapped. Make sure your input data is correct when supplying it as it can affect how people answer. As is, it results in embedded carriage returns in some strings after JSON parses it and creates the Ruby object.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple approach where we read the json file, take out the information as per the requirement into a ruby hash, convert the hash to a json string and put the string in a json file.

```
require "json"

my_file = JSON.parse(my_file.json) 

#reading the json file
to_be_generated = {}

#This hash will contain our desired  result. Now, let's go for the iteration. Here we check the genre of all the movies listed in the json file. 
#If the genre is ["Crime",  "Drama"], then the title and  (whatever you want to store in the json element) can be stored in a hash. 

for i in 0...my_file.count
      if my_file[i]["genre"] == ["Crime", "Drama"]

          # if you want only to check for Drama, then you can use as [@Neel][1] has pointed out, if my_file[["genre"].include?"Crime"

           to_be_generated.merge!(movie: my_file[i]["title"]) 
      end 

 #Add what else you want here. This is the Ruby hash.
end

json_string = to_be_generated.to_json() 


#It converts the Ruby hash into a json string . Now, the following helps the json string to be stored in a json file. 


File.open("my_json_file.json","w") do |f|
    f.write(json_string)
end
```

Comment: I'd recommend you try you code, showing what output you'd get. You can simplify your file write to `File.write('my_json_file.json', json_string)`. We don't use `for` loops in Ruby because they leak their variable. Use `each`, or `times`, with a block instead. Because the OP didn't supply the expected data result you don't know if it meets their requirement but give it a shot. For the future, it's better to close poorly asked questions than assume things.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use Array#select

```
selected_movies = json.compact.select { |movie| (["Crime", "Drama"] - movie[:genre]).empty? }

# or

selected_movies = json.compact.select { |movie| movie[:genre] == "Crime" && movie[:genre] == "Drama" }

File.open('selected_movies.json', 'w') { |f| f.puts selected_movies.to_json }
```

Comment: While there are many ways to get to a solution, why is this one the best choice? [teach, don't merely answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291533/128421).

Comment: @theTinMan after reviewing my answer, you're right, I should have taken the time to explain my solution. The advantage of the way I filtered the json, was that if the genre was not exactly equal to `%w[Crime Drama]` it would still match if the movie's genre was 'Drama', 'Crime', and 'Adventure'. Also order matters when comparing arrays so `[1, 2]` does not equal `[2, 1]`. Other than that I think your answer is better, because of the context and instruction you provided.

Comment: Order of the array does matter. I'll add a note that describes the issues, because they can make or break code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem when using `select`:

```
require 'json'

json_data = '
[{"rating":"9.3", "title":"The Shawshank Redemption", "genre":["Crime", "Drama"]},
{"rating":"9.0", "title":"Interstellar", "genre":["Adventure", "Sci-Fi"]}]'

output_json = JSON[json_data].select { |hash|
  hash['genre'] == %w[Crime Drama]
}.to_json
puts output_json
```

The generated JSON would be:

```
[{"rating":"9.3","title":"The Shawshank Redemption","genre":["Crime","Drama"]}]
```

If you want to write the data to a file use `File.write(...)`:

```
File.write(
  'output.json',
  output_json
)
```

[`JSON[json_data]`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-c-5B-5D) is a shortcut for parsing or generating JSON. If you pass in a string it'll assume you want to create a Ruby object of that string by parsing it. If you pass an array or a hash it'll serialize it and output a String.

[`File.write`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-i-write) is inherited from IO and makes it easy to (over)write a file.

---

> Also order matters when comparing arrays so `[1, 2]` does not equal `[2, 1]`...

That's true. It's not an issue if the values are coming from a form, or another source that's controlled by the programmer so the order is known and enforced. It breaks down when dealing with arrays where the order or the case could vary:

```
['a', 'b'] == ['a', 'b'] # => true
['a', 'b'] == ['b', 'a'] # => false
```

As for when the order varies, the comparison can change a little and still work:

```
(['a', 'b'] - ['a', 'b']).empty? # => true
(['a', 'b'] - ['b', 'a']).empty? # => true
```

The case can vary, but can be easily handled by normalizing and a bit more code:

```
[['A', 'b'], ['a', 'b']].map { |ary| ary.map(&:downcase) }.inject(:-).empty? # => true
[['A', 'b'], ['B', 'a']].map { |ary| ary.map(&:downcase) }.inject(:-).empty? # => true
```